# casting string to date not working on empty strings in Netezza

Tags: sql, string, date, casting, netezza

I have a string field which is of the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I need to convert it to a date field.

This is my SQL query:

```
select cast(rpad(trim(field_name),10,' ') as date) as field_name
from table_name
```

It works fine for records that have values, but not for records that are empty strings

I also tried using to_date function, but it gives an error saying "Invalid Date"

Answer (score 1):

Check the below query.

`SELECT TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM CAST("YourStringColumn" AS DATE))`

Comment: Hi Venk, 
I did try that before, it gives me an "Invalid Date" error

Comment: I am creating a table and I need that field as date in the new table.

Answer (score 1):

Netezza doesn't like to convert an empty string to a date - unlike SQL Server - so it's good to use a case statement to convert the empty string to a null.  Try this:

```
select case when field_name = '' then NULL else date(field_name) end as field_name
from table_name;
```